# Cómo usar getMoment para devolver la fecha de nacimiento en años y meses

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Una cadena con el valor de la edad del usuario (`x` Año(s), `y` Mes(es)).

En un sistema el usuario selecciona la FECHA a través de un calendario y en otro campo devuelve la edad.

Tengo dos variables definidas:

```
var years = moment().diff(getMoment(dateOfBirth), 'years');
var months = moment().diff(getMoment(dateOfBirth), 'months');
```

Y una máquina virtual que devuelve la cadena de edad del usuario "año y edad".

```
vm.idadeDoUsuario = years + ' ano' + 'e' + months + ' months';
```

Resultado obtenido: 1 año y 13 meses, pero ¿no serían 2 años?.

¿Qué cálculo debo hacer?

Comment: Nota al margen: [Moment.js está descontinuado](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Answer (score 0):

Moment tiene un objeto duration que puedes usar de esta forma

```
let dateOfBirth = moment('06/18/2021');
let duration = moment.duration(moment().diff(dateOfBirth));

let years = duration.years();
let months = duration.months();

vm.idadeDoUsuario = years + ' ano' + 'e' + months + ' months';
```

**Nota**

agregando información al comentario que te hicieron, si, momentjs está descontinuado los creadores ya no seguirán actualizando la librería, ellos mismos recomiendan usar date-fns pero de todos modos momentjs todavía sigue siendo una buena librería que aún esta soportada por todos los navegadores mayormente usados